# Populating a 3D array of structures in C

Tags: c

I have a 3D array of structures. The 3D grid is such that each of the three sides are equal. Each cell of the 3D grid has 5 elements, say color, temperature, B(x), B(y) and B(z). I have to populate each cell of the array of structures with 5 binary files, one for each element.

The array of structures look like this:

```
struct physical
{
  float color;
  float temperature;
  float Bx,By,Bz;
};
extern struct physical ***physical;
```

What I need is some idea how I would carry out the populating of the arrays in C.

I have the following code that I have implemented to read the data from the binary files into the array of structures:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int i,j,k,ibox;         /* Loop indices for the physical grid */

FILE *p,*q,*r,*s,*t;

p = fopen("phys_col_0107.bin","rb");
q = fopen("phys_temp_0107.bin","rb");
r = fopen("phys_Bx_0107.bin","rb");
s = fopen("phys_By_0107.bin","rb");
t = fopen("phys_Bz_0107.bin","rb");

if (!p)      { printf("Unable to open color file!"); return 0; }
else if (!q) { printf("Unable to open the temp file!"); return 0; }
else if (!r) { printf("Unable to open the Bx file!"); return 0; }
else if (!s) { printf("Unable to open the By file!"); return 0; }
else if (!t) { printf("Unavle to open the Bz file!"); return 0; }

for ( j = 0 ; j < ny ; j++ )
{
  for (k=0;k<nz;k++)
  {
    for (i=0;i<nx;i++)
    {
      fread( &physical[i][j][k].color       , sizeof(physical[i][j][k].color)       , 1 , p ) ;
      fread( &physical[i][j][k].temperature , sizeof(physical[i][j][k].temperature) , 1 , q ) ;
      fread( &physical[i][j][k].Bx          , sizeof(physical[i][j][k].Bx)          , 1 , r ) ;
      fread( &physical[i][j][k].By          , sizeof(physical[i][j][k].By)          , 1 , s ) ;
      fread( &physical[i][j][k].Bz          , sizeof(physical[i][j][k].Bz)          , 1 , t ) ;
    }
  }
}

fclose(p);
fclose(q);
fclose(r);
fclose(s);
fclose(t);
```

I just need to know whether I am going about this the right way.....thanks!!

Comment: `memset(...)` not an option?

Comment: I've only just heard of memset from you Cole......an example??

Comment: See [this reference page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/).

Comment: Do you mean you have a data file for color, another for temperature, a 3rd for Bx, and two more for By and Bz? Or a file for each 'physical' instance?

Comment: Yes Graham, one data file for each. As I was saying to Michael below, it would probably be more appropriate if the data was in binary format. That way, it could simply be dropped into the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few ways to do this off the top of my head:

1. Have your data be equal to the size of your 3D array.  Pad the unused or empty elements with 0s or so other sentinel value so you know it is "not real."  This is less space efficient, but makes reading and setting the data as simple as a single fread() call.
2. Use an RLE type scheme where you have a 1 byte where the top bit says if the next run is valid data or empty followed by the number of bytes in the run (up to 127 or 128 if 0 runs are not allowed).  If valid data, read that many structures in and directly load them into your grid.  If invalid run, skip that many structures or mark them some how as invalid.  Advantage being it is pretty space efficient, but slower to read as it will take multiple IO calls.
3. XML data format where you can set each element as a type in the XML file.  Easy to edit the data file, but much slower to populate your structure and much larger on disk that then above binary techniques.

Comment: I was thinking that Michael, otherwise nonsensical stuff would fill unallocated positions in the array. I'm a complete novice to your other suggestions, but willing to research them.

Comment: BTW, memset() would be useful only for filling the entire array with a single set value.  I do not believe this is what you were trying to do.

Comment: No, memset looks like it's a brute force option. I was leaning towards fread() but that seems to work best when the input files are of binary type.

Comment: Binary type will be your easiest option.  Anything else will require code to convert the text to binary before you drop it into your array.